# App not being showed to various tablets even if they have SIM card in them

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

My mainfest.xml permission , features and the application specification looks like this :

```
 <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="pj.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="pj.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".Volley.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">...........................
............................................
..


...</application>
```

>

And my build.grade (app level ) the default configs are like this :

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pj.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 2016061714
        versionName "2.5.3"
    }
```

But when i publish the app in the playstore, those apps are not visible to certain tables including **galaxy tab 4**  (it has SIM card in it  api level is more than 16) but it runs fine in the tables if i install apk in them directly.

What might be the reason? Thanks in advance guys .

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" / these two might not be present on your device

Comment: they have   camera

Comment: is it   not  avaliable  in all?

Comment: it would be better if i add "required " = false instead of just auto focus right ? and you believe it will address to more devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made the auto focus  optional and i was able to reach 1900 more devices and the tab was among them .

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```